# why return data is not displaying?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I checked with `console.log` the data is showing but in the main page data is not displaying, i don't understand what is wrong here , please help me thanks in advance

```
useEffect(() => {
  const newArr = [...messages, ...receiveMessages]
  console.log("newArr", newArr)
    newArr.map(m => 
     console.log(m.type,m.msg)
     )
}, [messages, receiveMessages]);

 
 { newArr ? newArr.map((m) => {
      return <div style={{float :'right'}}>{m.msg}</div>
  })
  : null 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use newArr as a state variable.

```
const [newArr, setNewArr] = React.useState(null)
useEffect(() => {
  setNewArr([...messages, ...receiveMessages])
}, [messages, receiveMessages, setNewArr]);
```

Comment: but `newArr` data is showing empty in `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

You declared the `newArr` variable inside useEffect with `const` keyword, scope of this keyword is inside pair of brackets so it is undefined outside of `useEffect`, that is the reason why your render code returns `null`.

You can move the `const newArr = [...messages, ...receivedMessages]` out of `useEffect` function, it works but it is not recommended, you will got warning or linting error when use linting tool (eslint, etc.)

Best approach is store `newArr` as state

```
const [newArr, setNewArr] = React.useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setNewArr([...messages, ...receiveMessages])
}, [messages, receiveMessages]);
```

Comment: but `newArr` data is showing empty in `console.log`

Comment: `setNewArr` runs asynchronously, so if you `console.log` right after `setNewArr`, the value is still the default value `[]`, it has not been updated yet. To get the updated value you should use another useEffect like this: `useEffect(() => console.log(newArr), [newArr])`;

Comment: is it ok if we use multiple `useEffect` in a functional component

Comment: Very common in real life project. For sure !